# getting dial tcp: i/o timeout when accessing internet from a service inside a container

Tags: docker, go, pubnub

I am using PubNub (GO SDK) publish/subscribe service to receive messages but I am not receiving any messages even when I am able to ping `google.com` from inside the container.

In the Pubnub logs, every time my program tries to connect to the origin (Pubnub server), I am getting "dial tcp: i/o timeout" error. I guess this is due to the slow internet connection either on the host or in the container.

What should I do to get around this error?

Answer (score 6):

I was to solve this error by including Google DNS (8.8.8.8) in my machine's nameservers. I think this error was due to the slow domain resolution process as my machine was getting DNS from DHCP.

I followed these steps:

1. Set static DNS in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`file:

   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
2. Configure your PC so that it uses user-provided DNS, instead of obtaining it from DHCP. For that, open this file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and add this line:

   supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
3. Restart network manager using:

   sudo service network-manager restart